# PHP application index.php not working in browser

Tags: php, dockerfile

I have deployed a php code into docker container but it's not working and giving following error in the browser.

**Error in Browser: http://localhost/index.php **

```
Warning: include_once(): Failed opening '//include//basePage.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in /var/www/html/index.php on line 10

Warning: include_once(//include//class.geoservice.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/index.php on line 11

Warning: include_once(): Failed opening '//include//class.geoservice.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in /var/www/html/index.php on line 11

Warning: require_once(//include//basePage.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/include/calcs/interfaceHomeCalc.php on line 6

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '//include//basePage.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in /var/www/html/include/calcs/interfaceHomeCalc.php on line 6*
```

However, if i copy a simple "hello world" index.php in the same code then that works fine.

The same php code is working fine on IIS but now I am trying it on linux docker container.
Here is my Dockerfile for the same.

```
COPY . /var/www/html
COPY vhost.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
EXPOSE 80
#EXPOSE 8931
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html
ENV APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data \
    APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data
```

Here is my vhost.conf file..

```
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    <Directory "/var/www/html">
        AllowOverride all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Kindly advise what could be wrong!!

Comment: Q: Why is your index.php looking for `'//include//basePage.php` (with double-slashes)?  That doesn't seem right.  Q: Does basePage.php exist in your Docker image?  Where?

Comment: index.php has a reference of basePage.php in it.

```include_once(INCLUDE_DIR . "basePage.php");```

and the path location inside container is as below:

```/var/www/html/index.php
/var/www/html/include/basePage.php```

Comment: I updated below path in index.html

Comment: I updated below path in index.html
```
    define("INCLUDE_DIR", $_SERVER['APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH'] . "//include//");
```
to

```
    define("INCLUDE_DIR", $_SERVER['APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH'] . "/var/www/html/include/");
```

now I am getting different error in browser:

```
Deprecated: Non-static method Logger::logError() should not be called statically in /var/www/html/include/errorHandler.php on line 29
2: filemtime(): stat failed for \\USDFW14AS159V\GHRMData\data\ghrmfiles\\intros\JP-COL\01_guideline.pdf:
```

Comment: sorry i meant by  **index.php** in my above comment

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the php code is written to run on windows platform and I need to modify it according to Linux. That'll definitely fix the issues with it.